# To be or to make someone

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> The Board of Control for Cricket in India (BCCI) has approached World Cup winners Madan Lal and Gautam Gambhir, the former India cricketers, **to be a part of the Cricket Advisory Committee (CAC)**. Both the former Delhi giants confirmed to The Hindu that they are willing to be a part of CAC.

[Link](https://www.thehindu.com/sport/cricket/bcci-set-to-appoint-madan-lal-gautam-gambhir-as-cac-members/article30550290.ece?homepage=true)

I think instead of **to be a part of** **to make them a part of** should be used.

Answer (score 1):

No, adding the verb “make” doesn’t work to improve the sentence.

Cutting back the complex phrasing (typical of news articles), the sentence reduces to:

> The Board has approached them **to be** a part of the CAC.

There is an implication the “approach” involves an invitation “to be a part of...”.

Your proposal is to use another verb, “to make”. So it essentially becomes:

> The Board has approached them **to make** them a part of the CAC.

This would imply that the approach itself “makes” them part of the CAC. But I see the intended meaning here as involving an invitation, or offer, to be accepted or rejected. The approach alone does not make them part of the CAC, they need to accept first.

A better way to phrase the sentence might have been:

> The Board has approached them with an offer to be a part of the CAC.